# I can't display name while I'm trying to do a profile why?

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I followed some tutos and I add user on firestore successly but I can't print this user on the profile page when the current user is logging because I'm having a error too in my front end.

This is my entire frontend with this error:

> The method '[]' can't be unconditionally invoked because the receiver can be 'null'.  Try making the call conditional (using '?.') or adding a null check to the target ('!')."

I tried ? and ! but with not success.

hope you help me !

```
 FutureBuilder(
              future: FirebaseFirestore.instance
            .collection('users')
            .doc('uid')
            .get(),
              builder: (context, snapshot) {
                if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
                  return Text(snapshot.data['displayName'],
                  );
                } else {
                  return Text("Loading...");
```

**and my backend if needed**

```
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';

Future userSetup(String displayName) async {
  CollectionReference users = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('Users');
  FirebaseAuth auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
  String uid = auth.currentUser!.uid.toString();
  await users.doc(uid).set({'displayName': displayName, 'uid': uid });
  final result = await users.doc(uid).get();
  final data = result.data() as Map<String, dynamic>;
  return data['displayName'];
}
```

Comment: This has come up quite regularly. Did you check https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgoogle-cloud-firestore%5D%5Bflutter%5D+The+method+%27%5B%5D%27+can%27t+be+unconditionally+invoked+because+the+receiver+can+be+%27null%27.?

Comment: Yes I tried many things but no solutions for my problem, I tried to add 'as Map' somewhere, `.toString()`  and it's doesn't work, I'm maybe missing something...